# My code doesn't receive a message from xserver

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I want to receive a message from xserver when I close my window.
(when I hit the 'X' button')

For example, I have a list of windows that are currently opened. (can be referred by `dayRecord`.)
I want to print that "window closed!" when I click the x button on a terminal.
But though I clicked it, I couldn't get any message from xserver.
Also, that `XNextEvent` is blocking.

I've test this exact same logic with a window generated in my code using `XCreateSimpleWindow`,
and it worked perfectly.

I can even close an existing window I created manualy by `XDestroyWindow`.
So, I think there is no difference between a window that is created by the code
and created before the code starts once if I have a window id.
But somehow, I cannot get any message from a former one.

This is my code.
It is trying to get a list of windows that are opened.
And within them, when I close a terminal it should print "window closed!"

```c
void windowManager() {
    // getting a text viewer to be traced
    char **textViewers = getTextViewers();
    // retreiving new record of a day
    DayRecord *dayRecord = getNewDayRecord();
    // save an x11 display, and currently opened windows into the day record
    Display *display = recordInit(dayRecord);
 
    Window whatToClose;
    for (int i = 0; i < dayRecord->recordCnt; ++i) {
        printf("currently opened: %s %lu\n", dayRecord->record[i].name, dayRecord->record[i].window);

        // for example: i want to know when a terminal is closed. (before the program starts, it should be opened, or it crashes.)
        if (strcmp(dayRecord->record[i].name, "gnome-terminal-server") == 0)
            whatToClose = dayRecord->record[i].window;

        addInfoSpace(display, dayRecord->record + i, textViewers);
    }

    printf("let's close %lu: %s\n", whatToClose, getWindowName(display, whatToClose));

    // window close detecting logic down here...
    Atom wmDelete = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, whatToClose, &wmDelete, 1);

    XEvent xEvent;
    printf("I am listening!\n");

    while (True) {
        XNextEvent(display, &xEvent);
        if (xEvent.type == ClientMessage && xEvent.xclient.data.l[0] == wmDelete) {
            printf("window closed!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    char *json = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100000);
    dayRecordToJSON(dayRecord, json);
    printf("%s", json);

    // freeing memories
    free2dArray((void **)textViewers, MAX_FILE_COUNT);
    freeDayRecord(dayRecord);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many things and this worked.
If you're trying to do the same thing, please check the code.
But, I am not sure if this is a right way to do.
Maybe there can be a safer and right way to do this but this works anyway.

```c
    // ...
    Atom wmDelete = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, whatToClose, &wmDelete, 1);
    XSelectInput(display, whatToClose, SubstructureNotifyMask);

    XEvent xEvent;
    printf("I am listening!\n");

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &xEvent);

        if (xEvent.type == DestroyNotify) {
            printf("window closed!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    // ...
```